# All possible 0 and 1 matrices of a normal graph

Tags: matlab, matrix

To better explain what I need, here is my first code:

```
function allpos = f1(x)
allpos=reshape(permute((dec2base(0:power(2,x*x)-1,2)-'0'),[3 2 1]),x,x,[]);
```

This code does exactly what I need it to. If the users inputs `f1(2)`, it returns every matrix from `[0 0; 0 0]` to `[1 1; 1 1]`. However, it also gives me a lot of useless matrices. I only want matrices that are mirrored across the diagonal, with only zeros on the diagonal.

To put more simply, for `f1(3)`, I only want 
`[0 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0]` to `[0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 0]`. That means that if I run the new `f1(3)`; it will return 8 matrices, not 512.

How do I rewrite the function to do this? I know that it will require some sort of addition of a triangular matrix and its transposed self, but I cant piece it together. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can probably be made more concise but the following does what you ask.

```
function allpos = f1(x)
N = (x-1)*x / 2;
z = permute(dec2base(0:power(2,N)-1,2)-'0',[3 2 1]);
allpos = zeros(x,x,power(2,N));
idx = repmat(logical(tril(ones(x),-1)),[1,1,power(2,N)]);
allpos(idx) = z(:);
allpos = permute(allpos,[2 1 3]);
allpos(idx) = z(:);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to @jodag's one, but more concise...

```
function allops=f1(x)
allops=zeros(x,x,2^(sum(1:x-1)));
allops(find(triu(ones(x),1))+x^2*(0:2^(sum(1:x-1))-1))=[dec2base(0:2^(sum(1:x-1))-1,2)-'0'].';
allops=allops+permute(allops,[2 1 3])
end
```

Comment: The only issue with this code is that the reflection doesn't populate in the final matrix correctly. For example: this returns the final matrix of [0 0 1; 1 0 1; 1 0 0] rather than [0 0 1; 0 0 1; 1 1 0]. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, that depends on how you define the symmetry.  See my edit now